# Does DB2 Support temporal tables join and aggregation?

Tags: sql, db2

I am looking for a resource which indicates whether Db2 on Ubuntu supports temporal tables join and aggregation or not.

Example:

```
customer (
  customer_id ,
  name ,
  address ,
  valid_period ,
  tx_period 
);

orders (
  order_id ,
  customer_id,
  order_total,
  valid_period ,
  tx_period 
);
```

Does DB2 support temporal join for these kind of tables on period fields?

Comment: Your link is to Db2 Event Store, not the Db2 database system. Are you looking for Db2? Which platform / OS? You can join data from temporal tables. To make your question more suited for Stack Overflow and easier to answer, please include an example of your type of tables / queries

Comment: @data_henrik I am using Ubuntu 22 and i provided example in my explanation, I can not any resource even in IBM site regards to supporting join and aggregation for bi-temporal tables, unless the link I provided which is related to time series data, if you have any resources plead kindly provide it to me.

Comment: What platform and version of Db2 are you connecting to?

Comment: If you already have the data and know what kind of query to write, why not try it? If it does not work, ask here again. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The Db2 documentation has information on [restrictions for system-period temporal tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-restrictions). They also apply for bi-temporal tables. Next, look at [querying bi-temporal tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=bt-querying). It is combining predicates on application periods and system periods.

Comment: The links that you are provided does not contain any information about Join or agrregation, please provide resources about these two operators if exists.

Comment: Again, have you tried it? The links contain the restrictions what SQL clauses are not supported. Could you turn that into a list of supported features...? ;-)